# NSNumberFormatter currency negative number

Tags: foundation, nsnumberformatter

My current code is

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[f setCurrencySymbol:NSLocalizedString(@"CURRENCY", @"Get Currency")];
NSString * stringCurrecy = [f stringFromNumber:(-70.00)];
```

I'm using `NSLog` to check the string currency and it's printing "($ 70.00)". 
I changed "(", ")" symbol. How can I achieve this:

```
( $ 70.00 ) -> - $70.00 or $ -70.00
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the negative format.
Add this line:

```
[f setNegativeFormat:@"-¤#,##0.00"];
```

but maybe you just want to set the locale with `[f setLocale:]` instead of setting every format option on your own.

(and next time post code that does compile.)

Comment: ( 70,00 $) -> - 70,00 $ i would like to display based on localisation. anyone give solution

Answer (score 5):

I have a NSNumber category that does this:

```
@implementation NSNumber (Formatter)

- (NSString *)currencyStringValue
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
    formatter.negativePrefix = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"- %@", formatter.currencySymbol];
    formatter.negativeSuffix = @"";

    return [formatter stringFromNumber:self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting negativeFormat to "-" almost worked for me, but it was dropping off the currency symbol.  At least for en_US locale, this fits my needs:

```
NSLocale *US = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormatter setCurrencyCode:currencyCode];
[currencyFormatter setLocale:priceLocale];

//manually add - prefix to positive format...
NSString *negFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",currencyFormatter.positiveFormat];
[currencyFormatter setNegativeFormat:negFormat];
```

I'm not sure whether this is appropriate for all locales, but it works for en_US.